# Add metadata for all calls to gRPC service

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

How do i add metadata for all calls to a service? I know how to send metadata for a specific call but i cant seem to find how to add standard metadata for all calls.

I tried to use a client interceptor to add the metadata there but don't seem like i can manipulate the headers for the context here.

I'm using gRPC in .net framework, not .net core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a *client* call (rather than a server call), you should be able to do this in an interceptor, by overriding the client call - for example:

```cs
public override AsyncClientStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse> AsyncClientStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context, AsyncClientStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
{
    Metadata newMetadata = // your logic here
    context = new ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse>(context.Method,
        context.Host, context.Options.WithHeaders(newMetadata));
    return base.AsyncClientStreamingCall(context, continuation);
}
```

(you'd need to override all 5 client-call methods; `AsyncClientStreamingCall`, `AsyncDuplexStreamingCall`, `AsyncServerStreamingCall`, `AsyncUnaryCall` and `BlockingUnaryCall`)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I managed to miss the WithHeaders method :) This works, i would never have expected to have to overwrite the entire context with a new one.

Comment: also im having alot of trouble finding any good documentation for grpc that would explain things like interceptors, metadata etc, i tried finiding the answer for this for quite a long time before i gave up and came here. Any resource you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @schh I agree, some parts are badly documented. I maintain protobuf-net.Grpc, which enables code-first gRPC scenarios in .NET by building on top of the Google/Microsoft bits, so I had to dig pretty deep to find things. If you have any specific questions, I can probably help - but I can't promise an open ended documentation source :/

Comment: oh nice :) that would be fantastic, I'm in the process of migrating from wcf to grpc atm so im sure ill have some questions at some point, so far its been fairly easy to get things working, just a couple of these things ive had issues with. ill research diligently before i come to you. Thanks for offering, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @schh it may be too late, but this might be useful: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/tree/main/examples/wcf-port

Comment: Ive looked through the repo and i think if i can get this working in .net framework this would grant you a free coffee :) My end goal is to port my entire project to .net core, but i need to do it in increments so if i can get grpc working in .net framwork. As i understand from the docs if i implement the server with Grpc.Core i can still use protobuf.net.Grpc for the codefirst parts? Project analyzer still claims System.ServiceModel isnt supprted, im using the primitives package so i think this is false but wanna be sure before i start this process.

Comment: @schh yes, it all works in both .net core and .net framework, and .net 5; there are alternative attributes in the library if you want to avoid the service-model ones, see `[Service]`. You should also check out protobuf-net.BuildTools which adds IDE integration and analyzers - so it tells you about problems as soon as you type them
 (and soon, AOT compilation)

Comment: ok excellent, i got stuck on creating and starting the server, since i now dont have a autogenerated class to up for the binding like this:

Services = { ServerInformationService.BindService(serverInformationService).Intercept(versionInterceptor) },

Comment: @schh k, I can try and look at this on Monday, but so that I get the scenario right: you want to add a client side interceptor in .NET Framework (so: using the Google transport, i.e. Grpc.Core), that transparently adds metadata to the requests. Is that right? I'm confused, because it *looks* like your code (message above) is server registration... but you were talking about client interceptors. So please clarify: client or server here?

Comment: @schh in which case, you *should* just need to use `.Intercept` on the channel? https://grpc.github.io/grpc/csharp/api/Grpc.Core.Interceptors.ChannelExtensions.html#Grpc_Core_Interceptors_ChannelExtensions_Intercept_Grpc_Core_ChannelBase_Grpc_Core_Interceptors_Interceptor_

Comment: ok great thank you:) yes i have both, client adds the metadata and i validate it in another interceptor serverside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225896/discussion-between-schh-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: @MarcGravell is it possible to achieve this in protobuf-net grpc?

Comment: @AsımGündüz yes, interceptors work identically with protobuf-net.Grpc - how you *attach* them may vary a little, but not much

Answer (score 4):

More elegant solution for the client (valid for all requests):

```
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel("localhost", 5001, ssl);
var invoker = channel.Intercept(m => { m.Add("my-custom-header", "my value 123"); return m; });
var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(invoker);
```

Comment: Thanks, after spending a day NOT getting my interceptor to work, this one-liner did the trick - nice!